# Access edittext Of Activity from BroadcastReceiver Class in android using kotlin

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, kotlin

I want to disable my edittext field if no internet connection is available. So, for that, i had make broadcastreceiver class to detect network change activities and when i receive broadcast that no internet connection is available, at that time i want to disable my edittext field and as internet connection is made on by user the field should be enabled automatically. Most important thing is that i am doing this thing using kotlin and i had found many solutions but all are for java.
So, please help me how can i do that. I had tried to get class instance for accessing edittext like below

```
var activityInstance = SetProfileActivity::class.objectInstance
```

and by using activityInstance object i tried to access my edittext like below

```
activityInstance.myEtId.setEnabled(false)
```

but i can't access it and it returns null.
How can i do this?

Comment: Do **NOT** create a `static` reference to an activity. First, you are causing a memory leak. Second, there is no requirement for the activity to exist (e.g., broadcast received sometime after the process is terminated). And, on Android 8.0+, you cannot listen for this broadcast via a manifest-registered receiver. Use `registerReceiver()` *inside* the activity rather than a manifest-registered receiver, and you will clear up these problems.

Comment: Yes, i also had tried this out and registered my broadcast receiver in my activity class but i till can't access my edittext.... i am trying it from last 2 days but i got solution recently that i have to declare my broadcastreceiver class as inner class..
By the way...thanks for support!!!

Comment: Then I suggest that you provide a [mcve] showing this code. That would include the entire source code to the activity, including its receiver that you are registering via `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: My proble is solved but if you want to see my source code then i don't have any problem. Let me answer my question and add my source code in it! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got Solution....I have to register my receiver in my activity class and important thing is that declare broadcastreceiver class as inner class to access elements of activity.

e.g.

```
inner class InternetOnReceiver : BroadcastReceiver(){
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        etLocationPicker.hint = "Pick Location"
        etLocationPicker.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd upvote your answer, if you'd cleaned the code up a bit before pasting it. We only need to see the minimum requirements for a working version of your solution (not your entire application! )

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. i am new to stackoverflow so, thanks for helping me for improve my impressions of stackoverflow. i will keep your suggestions in my mind next time and i had edited my answer and cleaned it as you suggested. now you can check it and can upvote it if you found it right! Thanks again! @Lissy